Gradient background transitioning animations not working with react-router
I am working on a hobby project.
I have a gradient background, and trying to create an animation whenever I switch between routes. For example, if I have background-color: linear-gradient(green, red) in the login page, and background-color: linear-gradient(blue, yellow) on the home page, the colors do change, but immediately - there is no animated transition.
I saw an example in this answer, and based on that created the following html file, which works fine:
test.html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: red;
      }
      @property --clr1{
        syntax: '<color>';
        initial-value: rgb(0, 255, 0);
        inherits: false;
      }

      @property --clr2 {
        syntax: '<color>';
        initial-value: rgb(106, 255, 0);
        inherits: false;
      }
      #test {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: linear-gradient(var(--clr1), var(--clr2));
        transition: --clr1 3s, --clr2 3s;
      }
      .cls1 {
        --clr1: blue;
        --clr2: lightblue;
      }
      .cls2 {
        --clr1: rgb(149, 255, 0);
        --clr2: rgb(196, 3, 64);
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function func() {
        document.querySelector('#test').classList.remove('cls1')
        document.querySelector('#test').classList.add('cls2')
      }
    </script>
    <div id="test" width="100" class="cls1" height="100%" onclick="func()" ></div>
  </body>

</html>

Now, I tried applying it for my project, here:
app.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Login';
import AdVentureTheme from './themes/AdVentureTheme';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import CompanyHome from './Company/CompanyHome';
import './styles.css';

const GradientWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [className, setClassName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (location.pathname) {
      case '/login':
        setClassName('login');
        break;
      case '/company/home':
        setClassName('company-home');
      default:
        setClassName('');
        break;
    }
  }, [location]);

  return <div className={className} id='gradient-background' >{children}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={AdVentureTheme}>
      <Router>
        <GradientWrapper >
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login  />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/company/home" element={<CompanyHome />} />
          </Routes>
        </GradientWrapper>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

using this css file:
styles.css
@property --gradientColorStart {
  syntax: '<color>';
  initial-value: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  inherits: false;
}

@property --gradientColorEnd {
  syntax: '<color>';
  initial-value: red;
  inherits: false;
}

#gradient-background {
  background: linear-gradient(var(--gradientColorStart), var(--gradientColorEnd));
  transition: var(--gradientColorStart) 3s, var(--gradientColorEnd) 3s;
}

.login {
  --gradientColorStart: red;
  --gradientColorEnd: aliceblue; 
}

.company-home {
  --gradientColorStart: olive;
  --gradientColorEnd: magenta;
}

But it's not working well, as the background color changes but there are no animated transitions.
